# How can I monitor changes to project properties in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

How can I listen for changes to project properties (ie, things that are changes in a project's Properties dialog pages)? I know that IPreferenceStore allows me to register a property change listener, but I don't know how to get a hold of the preference store for a particular project. Specifically, I'm writing a custom PropertyPage that needs to respond to changes in the various JDT property pages. I don't see an obvious hook into the availability of the project's preference store during the lifecycle of my own PropertyPage.

Comment: Project properties will be saved as a file, can you check the file only?

Comment: @Ryan, no that's not good enough. The file storage of properties is a internal implementation detail, so I can't know the name or location of the file (well, I can figure it out, but can't rely on that) nor that it even will be a file in later versions. I don't want to use any internal classes or "magic" knowledge. Plus, even if I did read the file, I'd have to know how to parse it.